# Fail to allocate large jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, out-of-memory, 64-bit

I am trying to execute the following function to create and initialize a large jagged array, where `T` is `Int16`, `NumOfRows` is `10000` and `NumOfColumns` is `1127211`.

```
public static T[][] Create<T>(int NumOfRows, int NumOfColumns, T Value)
{
    var Result = new T[NumOfRows][];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfRows; i++ )
    {
        Result[i] = new T[NumOfColumns];
        for (int j = 0; j < NumOfColumns; j++)
        {
            Result[i][j] = Value;
        }
    }
    return Result;
}
```

To my understanding, the total allocated memory should be roughly 20 gigabytes. The machines' physical RAM is 16 gigabytes, the size of the Windows swapping file is roughly 13 gigabytes. However, I'm getting an

`OutOfMemoryException`

during the allocation. The project is built as a 64 bit executable and the `App.config` used the

```
<runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

setting. Am I missing something? Is it impossible to allocate so much memory? Note that the array is jagged, which means that only the lines of the array need to be contiguous. Do you have any suggestions whether more memory can be made available configuration-wise? What other options are there for accessing memory?

Comment: Sounds like your out of memory... why do you think that's wrong?

Comment: I think the allocation should work because the .NET runtime is able to use Windows' virtual memory. Is that not the case? Or is the virtual memory insufficient?

Comment: It's impossible to tell by the data, but I would imagine at least a few good memory GBs are used by your OS and other running processes - do you have any evidence that negates this?

Comment: To my understanding (by inspection of the Windows Task Manager), about 3 gigabytes of RAM are used by running processes.

Comment: Try to split that into 5 process instances with 5th the size each (in terms of memory requirements) - if that fails, you know you're out of memory

Comment: It is not very typical to want to load so much data into RAM. Most applications that deal with GBs of data will store it in files and stream through it, pulling out only the interesting data for the task at hand. Why is it that you are loading everything into RAM?

Comment: @NightOwl888 That's a legitimate question. I have implemented two dynamic programming algorithms for the [Knapsack](http://www.diku.dk/~pisinger/codes.html) problem. I'm testing these using an instance library taken from [here](http://www.diku.dk/~pisinger/codes.html), for which the optimal objective values are known. I'm well aware that dynamic programming is a relatively basic approach. The implementations are able to solve smaller instances.

Comment: And on which allocation it fails (what is `i` at the moment of exception)?

Comment: Strangely, the symptoms have changed. If `T` is `Int32`, the allocation fails for row `8757`. If `T` is `Int16`, the machine freezes.

Comment: It is changing (perhaps with system load). If `T` is `Int32`, the allocation sometimes fails for row `9373`.

Comment: Yes, I mistyped. I have corrected it.

Comment: And what if you increase swap file size to say 50GB?

Comment: @Evk: Increasing the swap file size resolved the issue. Thanks for your kind help, folks! Please consider converting your suggestion into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2017, open the project Properties and ensure that Build -> Platform Target is Any CPU and that you've unchecked "Prefer 32-bit".

I was able to reproduce your array (about 22.7 GB) on my 64-bit machine with only 8GB of physical memory.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the checkbox you mention is already unchecked.

Comment: When your app is running, do you see *32 by the name in Task Manager? And your operating system is 64-bit Windows? Strange. Does it only fail when you're running inside vshost.exe?

Comment: I'm not running the implementaion as an application, but I am using VSTest from Visual Studio. Does that make differece?

Comment: VSTest has sketchy support for 64-bit, but try selecting the Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture -> X64 option.

Comment: Again, it works for me with vstext.executionengine.exe (without *32 in Task Manager) for the full 20+ GB.

Comment: Can you start with a blank solution and only add this one project and a test project with no extra references? That will help isolate if the runtime is downgrading you to 32-bit to accommodate another referenced assembly.

Comment: In a blank solution doing only the allocation, the allocation fails later (at row `9565`). I will try to change the size of the swap file later.